# Is it possble to bind the getClass of a table cell element to a viewController in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, viewcontroller

In ExtJS 6.02 I have an actioncolumn where cells have 2 buttons, each button has a `getClass` property with a method to determine the appropriate class.

Is it possible to have this method in the viewController?
I have tried adding it to the viewController but it's not being called.

Comment: Unfortunately, `getClass` was left out when the framework added declarative listeners.  I imagine you could set up a handler for when your actioncolumn renders, then dig into its children, and use [Ext.bind](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.html#method-bind) to set your function scope for getClass.

Comment: It's good to note that this was fixed in v6.2+, so if you get the chance to upgrade, I would recommend doing so.